# Configure the SSRS web server for additional paths

Tags: reporting-services, configuration, webserver, ssrs-2014

I am using SSRS 2014, and on the server it runs, it binds to port 80 and exposes two paths, `/Reports` and `/reportserver`. I know how to configure these through the SSRS Configuration Manager.

I am wondering about the web server in the backend running on port 80. Is this IIS under the covers? Or if not, is there a way to plug in additional configuration to it? Basically, all I am after is to be able to add a redirect from path `/` to `/Reports`, so if people just type `http://reports.mycompany.com`, they will automatically be redirected to `http://reports.mycompany.com/Reports`. Is this possible out of the box?

(I know my other option is to bind it to a port other than 80 and then use an actual web server like IIS or Apache on port 80 to act as a proxy for SSRS, but I am wondering if anyone know if what I want can be done out of the box – I am not sure if there are any performance impacts with this option.)

Comment: It's not IIS under the surface but if you install IIS on that server, change the default.asp page to redirect to the reports url.

Comment: If I install IIS on that same server, I would assume it would not be able to bind to port 80 since SSRS already is. Am I incorrect with that? Or is IIS smart enough to recognize that SSRS is present and play well with it?

Comment: No, Reporting Services grabs       http://machinename/Report and /ReportServer, not the root      http://machinename/. Reporting Services config lets you specify the foldernames it uses and the ports as well, if you don't want to use 80.